# Why does downloading the same file twice double the download speed?

Tags: performance, bandwidth, rate-limiting, android, throttling

I am testing a small home setup consisting of a Windows 10 system with a Firefox fork and a headless Android 9 device, the latter of which provides a wireless mobile hotspot with an unlimited data plan. According to a popular online [internet bandwidth test](https://fast.com/), my bandwidth averages at a stable 440-500 kB/s or 3.5-4.0 Mbit/s (which is significantly better than the contractually agreed limit of "up to 3 Mbit/s").

**Observation:** When downloading files, the speed always tops out at a measly 120-150 kB/s for a single file. Strangely, when the same file is downloaded twice in parallel, the speed for *each individual download* immediately rises to around 250 kB/s, corresponding in total to the measured bandwidth ceiling.

If one of the downloads is interrupted, the speed immediately drops again. Also, running more than two downloads in parallel results in diminished speeds. Instead of a second simultaneous download, any concurrent usage of bandwidth also has the same effect. I have therefore adopted the weird habit of running any download twice in parallel, unless some bandwidth is needed for other tasks such as streaming or video conferencing.

**Question:** What exactly is responsible for this strange behavior and *how can I ensure that even single connections always saturate the available bandwidth*?

Is it something inherent to the hardware? Or is there maybe a limit imposed by Android on the number of CPU cores used per connection or does Android shut down cores when only a single connection is active? Or is it maybe some Firefox setting?

Could this possibly even be a dishonest/fraudulent practise by the internet service provider, devised e.g. to prevent the usage of high-quality video streaming services with their cheapest mobile data plans (arguably the main contributor of bandwidth consumption in private households) and thereby coerce customers to "upgrade" to more expensive contracts? I.e. can ISPs throttle the bandwidth based on a customer's total number of active connections, such that a single connection can in practise never reach the advertised bandwidth (thereby limiting e.g. the usable resolution of video streaming content), while it is still technically possible to reach the advertised bandwidth by multiple concurrent connections and thereby keep the ISP out of legal problems?

Comment: Welcome, home and enduser questions are offtopic on serverfault, but shall be asked on superuser.com instead. Therefore I flagged this question for movement, which I suggest you the same because it will transfer this question to the correct site and does not give you a "strike" for crossposting.